# How to avoid ActionMailer::Preview committing data to development database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using `Rails 4.1.0.beta1`'s new Action Mailer previews and have the following code:

```
class EventInvitationPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def invitation_email
    invite = FactoryGirl.create :event_invitation, :for_match, :from_user, :to_user
    EventInvitationMailer.invitation_email(invite)
  end
end
```

This is all good until I actually try to preview my email and get an error saying that validation on a User object failed due to duplicate email addresses. Turns out that ActionMailer::Preview is writing to my development database.

While I could work around the validation failure or use fixtures instead of factories, is there any way to avoid ActionMailer::Preview writing to the development database, e.g. use the test database instead? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: I believe ActionMailer does know nothing about your User class, and this is not were to look to fix your issue. Search instead in your `event_invitation` factory, perhaps it creates a user record?

Comment: It does create a user record. As I mentioned in my question, it's trivial to avoid the problem with records, what I wanted to know if there's a way to use ActionMailer Preview without having to write to the development database.

What I've done for now is to simply use existing data -- but that means it must be pre-seeded.

Answer (score 20):

Cleaner/Easier (based on other answers) and tested with **Rails 7**: Do not change Rails' classes but create your own. Id addition to not change the controller but the `call` method of `ActionMailer::Preview`.

```rb
# app/mailers/preview_mailer.rb

class PreviewMailer < ActionMailer::Preview
  def self.call(...)
    message = nil
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      message = super(...)
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
    message
  end
end

# inherit from `PreviewController` for your previews

class EventInvitationPreview < PreviewController
  def invitation_email
    ...
  end
end
```

---

**OLD:**

You can simply use a transaction around email previews, just put this inside your `lib/monkey_mailers_controller.rb` (and require it):

```
# lib/monkey_mailers_controller.rb
class Rails::MailersController
  alias_method :preview_orig, :preview

  def preview
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      preview_orig
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call `.create` etc. in your mailer previews but nothing will be saved to database. Works in `Rails 4.2.3`.

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer (not that there is one as of this writing). This is the cleanest way to make this transaction wrapper apply to all mailer previews. Note: I thought I'd get clever and put this in `lib/monkey_patches`, which I load BEFORE `Rails.application.initialize!` and voila: I spent over an hour trying to figure out why my Rails mailer index was giving me url_for errors. TL;DR: Put this in the root of `lib` or in `config/initializers` and you are golden!

Comment: Working for me in Rails 5.2.3. I put the code in an initializer called `mailer_previews.rb`

Comment: A great approach, but Rails 6 autoloader changes will make it throw errors in a future version.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60154367/650475) for how to get past that.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** -- The original author of the ActionMailer preview feature (via the [MailView](https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view) gem) provides three examples of different supported approaches:

- Pull data from existing fixtures: `Account.first`
- Factory-like pattern: `user = User.create!` followed by `user.destroy`
- Stub-like: `Struct.new(:email, :name).new('name@example.com', 'Jill Smith')`

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

To elaborate on the challenge faced by the OP...

Another manifestation of this challenge is attempting to use `FactoryGirl.build` (rather than create) to generate non-persistent data. This approach is suggested by one of the top Google results for "Rails 4.1" -- http://brewhouse.io/blog/2013/12/17/whats-new-in-rails-4-1.html?brewPubStart=1 -- in the "how to use this new feature" example. This approach seems reasonable, however if you're attempting to generate a url based on that data, it leads to an error along the lines of:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Rails::Mailers#preview

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Using `FactoryGirl.create` (rather than build) would solve this problem, but as the OP notes, leads to polluting the development database.

If you check out the docs for the original [MailView](https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view) gem which became this Rails 4.1 feature, the original author provides a bit more clarity about his intentions in this situation. Namely, the original author provides the following three examples, all focused on data reuse / cleanup / non-persistence, rather than providing a means of using a different database:

```
# app/mailers/mail_preview.rb or lib/mail_preview.rb
class MailPreview < MailView
  # Pull data from existing fixtures
  def invitation
    account = Account.first
    inviter, invitee = account.users[0, 2]
    Notifier.invitation(inviter, invitee) 
  end

  # Factory-like pattern
  def welcome
    user = User.create!
    mail = Notifier.welcome(user)
    user.destroy
    mail
  end

  # Stub-like
  def forgot_password
    user = Struct.new(:email, :name).new('name@example.com', 'Jill Smith')
    mail = UserMailer.forgot_password(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Using FactoryBot's `build_stubbed` can help with the routing problem (it assigns a fake ID value): https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/c716ce01b448ce4e0bf855c5a2c63ecb9206322e/spec/acceptance/build_stubbed_spec.rb#L42

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner way to proceed is to prepend a module overriding and wrapping `preview` into a transaction:

```rb
module RollbackingAfterPreview
  def preview
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      super
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  class Rails::MailersController
    prepend RollbackingAfterPreview
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Rails 6:**

[@Markus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289295/650475) worked for me, except that it caused a nasty deprecation-soon-will-be-real error related to how Autoloading has changed in Rails 6:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants [many constants seemingly unrelated to what I actually did]
>
> Being able to do this is deprecated. **Autoloading during initialization is going to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.**
>
> [...]

Well, that's no good!

After more searching, [this blog](https://www.danott.co/today-i-learned/2019-10-16) and the docs for 
[`to_prepare`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events) helped me come up with this solution, which is just @Markus' answer wrapped in `to_prepare`.  (And also it's in `initializer/` instead of `lib/`.)

```
# /config/initializers/mailer_previews.rb
---
# Wrap previews in a transaction so they don't create objects.

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do

  class Rails::MailersController
    alias_method :preview_orig, :preview

    def preview
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        preview_orig
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I was finding that I had to reload the server in development to see changes in the preview anyways. Changing `to_prepare ` to `after_initialize` fixed an exception that I was seeing when trying to reload changes without restarting the server. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated object hierarchy, you can exploit transactional semantics to rollback the database state, as you would in a test environment (assuming your DB supports transactions). For example:

```
# spec/mailers/previews/price_change_preview.rb
class PriceChangeMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  #transactional strategy
  def price_decrease
    User.transaction do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :with_favorited_products) #creates a bunch of nested objects
      mail = PriceChange.price_decrease(user, user.favorited_products.first)
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Don't really want these objects committed to the db!"
    end
    mail
  end
end

#spec/factories/user.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...
    trait :with_favorited_products do
      after(:create) do |user|
         user.favorited_products << create(:product)
         user.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

We can't use user.destroy with dependent: :destroy in this case because destroying the associated products normally doesn't make sense (if Amazon removes me as a customer, they don't remove all the products I have favorited from the market).

Note that transactions are supported by [previous gem implementations of the preview functionality](http://thatalexguy.com/posts/2013-07-18-letter-bomb.html#transactional-previews). Not sure why they aren't supported by ActionMailer::Preview.